# Calculating determinant given a relation between two unknown elements

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, determinant

> If $a$ and $b$ are real and satisfy the relation $4a^2 + 3b^2 - 4ab - 4b + 2 \le 0$ then calculate the determinant of $$\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 4 & 4 \\ a & b & 2 \\ a^2 & b^2& 4\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> 1. $2$
> 2. $3$
> 3. $-3$
> 4. $0$

**My attempt:**

I first calculated the determinant in terms of $a$ and $b$:

$$\Delta = 4(b-a)(2-a)(2-b)$$

But I don't know how to use the relation given in the question to find a numerical value for $\Delta$.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4a^2 + 3b^2 - 4ab - 4b + 2 \le 0$

$(2a-b)^2 + 2 (b- 1)^2 \leq 0$

The LHS cannot be negative and for it to be zero, we must have, $a = \cfrac{b}{2} \ $ and $b = 1$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Try to prove that
$$4a^2 + 3b^2 - 4ab - 4b + 2 \le 0 \Longleftrightarrow \quad \left(a=\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad b=1\right)$$